Typescript complains on generic types
I have a groupBy function in Typescript that is responsible to group array objects by a key from every array:
export const groupBy = <T, K extends string>(array: T[], key: K): Record<K, T> => {


  return array.reduce((acc, item) => {

    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = []
    }

    acc[key].push(item)

    return acc
  }, {} as Record<K, T[]>)
}

const arr = [{name: "Car"}, {name: 'Color'}, {name: 'Car'}]

interface Data {
  name: string
}

const res = groupBy<Data[], 'Car' | 'Color'>(arr, 'name')
console.log(res)

What i want to achive is next:

To be able to add the array type
To be able to add the keys as
union type
To get the code suggestion when i will consume the result

 I added all types for that but i still get a TS error here (const res = groupBy<Data[], 'Car' | 'Color'>(arr, 'name')
):
Argument of type '{ name: string; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Data[][]'.
  Type '{ name: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Data[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.(2345)
const arr: {
    name: string;
}[]

How to fix the types to not get any errors?

What is T? The type of one element or the whole array? What is K? is it the object key or the set of possible values?

@Asking: You should start by answering this: what's the expected set of keys of your result. Should the resulting object have name as a key or rather Car and Color as keys? In other words, start from an untyped implementation that works correctly and then try to type it.

I think the K in key: K and in Record<K, T> should be two different types. The K in key: K should be keyof T. The K in Record<K, T> should either be string or a list of possible values that contain Car and Color.

It seems like you should first fix the JavaScript. That's probably not the expected behavior: https://jsfiddle.net/oxmg7rnL/ Please provide the expected result of your code. I have a fixed version that I could post as an answer after I can verify that it produces the expected result.

I agree with previous commenters: The code in this question is very weird; it doesn't group anything (or, rather, everything always goes into the same group). This doesn't feel like a good fit for Stack Overflow as currently asked, unless you're really asking how to turn T into T[] in your return type, which seems easy enough, just write Record<K, T[]> instead.

your code is mixing the array type (Data[]) with the array of items to be grouped. Here's how you can fix the problem and improve the type definitions to ensure TypeScript understands what you're trying to achieve.


// Group by function here
export const groupBy = <T, K extends keyof T>(array: T[], key: K): Record<T[K] extends string ? T[K] : string, T[]> => {
  return array.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const groupKey = item[key] as string; // we make sure that the key is a string

    if (!acc[groupKey]) {
      acc[groupKey] = [];
    }

    acc[groupKey].push(item);

    return acc;
  }, {} as Record<string, T[]>);
};

// Example data
interface Data {
  name: string;
}

const arr: Data[] = [{ name: "Car" }, { name: 'Color' }, { name: 'Car' }];

// use it here
const res = groupBy(arr, 'name');
console.log(res);



